# Quantity of ingredients to make 150 veg sandwiches

Tags: vegetarian, mayonnaise, sandwich, bulk-cooking, ingredients

I want to make  veg sandwiches on the occasion of Gurpurab. I'm expecting 150 guests. But I'm confused about how much mayonnaise or chesse and ketchup I should use. Please help.

Comment: Well, how much mayonnaise/cheese/ketchup do you use when you make one sandwich? This is not a type of food where it's difficult to scale the recipe up/down.

Comment: I have no idea, I never made any veg sandwich before. So I m completely clueless , I just want a rough idea.

Comment: It seems, then, like first you need to learn how to make a sandwich. Once you're good at that, you can determine how to make a bunch of them.

Comment: Part of the challenge of sandwiches is that the quantity of ingredients can vary quite a bit, particularly with condiments like mayonnaise. Two different sandwich makers might use double or even triple the quantity. You really do need a base recipe for a single sandwich, after which it's much easier to scale up.

Comment: You've tagged your question "vegetarian" so just in case you weren't aware, standard mayonnaise isn't vegetarian as it contains eggs - you might want to be careful about that and look out for specifically vegetarian or vegan substitutes.

Answer (score 4):

(Hopefully someone else can give a more specific recommendation, as I know this doesn’t completely answer your question)

The search term to use when looking for this sort of information is ‘quantity cooking’, and there are websites that have tables for how to cook for 25 or 50 people/portions

Of course, how much mayonnaise or other ingredient you use depends on the size of the bread or roll, but [1TB/sandwich](https://www.chef-menus.com/food-quantity-chart.html) for 150 sandwiches seems to be 96oz.

I have no idea exactly what sort of vegetables that you’re planning on using, but you might want to assemble a few sandwiches, weigh the contents, and extrapolate from there.  (I say this because so many websites assume meat or cheese sandwiches, so the vegetable amounts are garnishes, not the bulk of the sandwich; assembling a few sandwiches before measuring helps to average out any errors.

Another website recommends [120 sandwiches per 100 people](http://www.ellenskitchen.com/bigpots/plan/sandwich100.html), but it really depends on many issues, as large men are going to eat more than children, and people eat less in hot weather.

Comment: I think it might also vary depending on what exact sort of vegetarian sandwiches he's planning on making. If he's planning on a "western-style" vegetarian sandwich with cheese, tomato, and lettuce, that'd be a very different thing to a more "middle-eastern" sandwich with falafels, hummus, etc.